# How to combine two queries in to the one line query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to using the first query result to apply on the second query. Then I got some problems.

(My environment is `Node.js`, but it doesn't cause the influence of this question.)

---

### FIRST QUERY

```
SELECT (TO_SECONDS('2015-02-10 23:00:00') - TO_SECONDS(NOW())) AS remainSeconds
```

then I will get the numeric result 'remainSeconds' like '-1957'.

If 'remainSeconds' > 0 will run the second query.

### SECOND QUERY

```
// '...' is not important, so I skip them.

INSERT INTO tableA(...) SELECT ... FROM tableB
```

---

My problem summary :

> We know there is some delay between the two queries running. And this delay time will cause some critical problems in some cases.
>
> How to combine above two queries in to the one line query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `(TO_SECONDS('2015-02-10 23:00:00') - TO_SECONDS(NOW()))` in the where of your `SELECT`

e.g.

`INSERT INTO tableA(...) 
SELECT ... 
FROM tableB
WHERE (TO_SECONDS('2015-02-10 23:00:00') - TO_SECONDS(NOW())) > 0`

Comment: LOL.
I add the 'SELECT' this word between 'WHERE' and '(TO_SEC...', then got the wrong. Thank you very much!